# IE11 doesn't respect percent-based margin on inline-block elements

Tags: margin, percentage, internet-explorer-11, css

Widening and narrowing the browser window in IE11 does not reposition `inline-block` elements with a percent-based margin.  [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Impirator/RMsnL/3/) (it should work fine in other browsers, so be sure to open with IE).

You can programmatically apply a do-nothing style `onresize` (like `zoom: 1`) and that triggers a layout, but I'm hoping someone here knows of a CSS solve instead of that hacky workaround.

Sample markup:

```
<div>
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5%;
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I just bumped into the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Your provided fiddle is working great within my IE 11.

It is very hard to see, at the current 5% margin. If you change this to 1%, and begin resizing your browser - it becomes much more noticeable.

Hope this works! :)

Comment: @Jonathan I'm using Windows 7; 64-bit, what about y'all?

Comment: Windows 7, 64-bit for myself also. Good luck!